# AWS: WebSockets API as VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket

I have a Lambda in a private subnet in a VPC (Lambda needs ElastiCache). My Lambda doesn't need Internet access (therefore no NAT).

Can I setup a VPC endpoint for my WebSockets API? Whenever try to call the endpoint I get a `Endpoint request timed out`.

Update: It looks like I have to add "HTTPS" to my inbound Security Group. Can anybody explain why this is needed? Now at least "normal" API requests work but still no WebSockets... (

Comment: I am also facing similar issue with my WebSocket call back url.
I saw your question on aws forums, no replies though.

Could you please share if you found a solution already ?

Comment: It simply doesn't work with WebSockets (by design). WebSockets APIs are by design public APIs and can't be accessed using VPC endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with following steps:

1. Created 3 private subnets
2. Created a NAT gateway
3. Created route table with 3 private subnets.
4. Configured "private" route table with NAT gateway.